# Repeat image to extend header to fill screen

Tags: html, css, header, repeat

I have a Header (2300x328px) and another image (456x328px). Now I want this second image to extend this header to the left and right, that the header fills the whole width availiable.It needs to connect without overlapping, because there is a pattern.
Here is an image of what I mean: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVzIh.jpg
The circles are the pattern (why it should not overlap) And the Images to extend the header can be repeated infinitely.

Comment: do you mean the second image cover the first one?

Comment: No, It should extend it on the sides and should not overlap in any way

Comment: But you want it will be behind the first image right? otherwise you wouldn't mention the first image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the pattern to align exactly you need to align the background pattern according to the header image (ex. center, left etc) and then make sure the pattern starts at the right place.

I made a fiddle to explain what I mean - http://jsfiddle.net/taneleero/g99xa/

```
.header {
    background:url(http://i.imgur.com/BzVtzl4.jpg) repeat-x center;
}

.header img {
    display:block;
    margin:0px auto;
}
```

Comment: Nearly! But it should connect to the main header, right now part of the extra image is below the header. It shloud be "out of the window" that you cann't see the rest anymore

Answer (score 0):

You have to add div bot sides with `repeat-x`.
I make an example for you on jsFiddle.

**Html:**

```
<div id="header">
    <div class="extend"></div>
    <div id="logo"></div>
    <div class="extend"></div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
#header {
   display: inline-block;
   border: 1px solid black;
}
#header div {
    display: inline-block;
}
.extend {
    background-image: url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e2/Google_Chrome_icon_(2011).svg/64px-Google_Chrome_icon_(2011).svg.png');
    height: 60px;
    width: 100px;
}
#logo {
    background-image: url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/he/3/3f/Microsoft_Outlook_Icon.png');
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NBxHy/1/)

Answer (score -1):

// markup

```
<div id="header" style="height: 200px;"></div>
```

// css

```
#header {
    background: url(images/preloader-w8-cycle-black.gif) repeat-x;
}
```